# page is not displaying AJAX response as expected

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

My `contact.php` script successfully handles sending emails.

However, when submitting the form in `index.html`, instead of displaying the expected success message within the `.send-message` class, the browser shows an error message in JSON format.

Despite attempting to use AJAX, the request isn't triggering as expected, and the error message persists rather than showing the desired success message enclosed in a `<div class="sent-message" style="display: none;">`

In my `index.html`, there is a "Contact Us" form that send email via POST to `contact.php`. `contact.php` processes the form using PHPMailer and returns either true or false to `index.html`.

The error message shown in the picture is the `$responseString` from `contact.php`.

There are only two files involved in this issue: `index.html` and `contact.php`, which are responsible for handling the contact form. However, I'm unsure why the error message is not functioning correctly.

Could someone provide guidance on resolving this issue?
[image]

Contact.php

```
 $mail->send();
    // Manually construct success response
    $responseString = '{"success": true, "message": "Your message has been sent. Thank you!"}';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Manually construct error response
    $responseString = '{"success": false, "message": "Failed to send the message. Please try again later."}';
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $responseString;
```

index.html

```
  <div class="col-lg-8 mt-5 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-left">
    <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile Number"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="my-3">
        <div class="loading" style="display: none;">Loading</div>
        <div class="sent-message" style="display: none;">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
        <div class="error-message" style="display: none;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.php-email-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission

        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'forms/contact.php', // Make sure the path is correct
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json', // Expect JSON response from the server
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $('.error-message').hide(); // Hide any previous error message
                    $('.sent-message').text(response.message).show(); // Show success message
                } else {
                    $('.sent-message').hide(); // Hide any previous success message
                    $('.error-message').text(response.message).show(); // Show error message
                }
                $('.loading').hide(); // Hide the loading indicator
            },
            error: function() {
                $('.loading').hide(); // Hide the loading indicator
                $('.sent-message').hide(); // Hide any previous success message
                $('.error-message').text('An error occurred. Please try again later.').show(); // Show fallback error message
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: And honestly I can't see how this code could produce that output (but I'm happy to be proved wrong). Are you sure this is the code you're actually executing? The only bit missing is we can't see the html form tag to know if it contains the class to map to the selector of your .submit() binding. Try to make sure you provide a [mre] of the issue

Comment: This code really couldn't produce the shown result. The text `Error:`, where would that even be coming from? It is not contained in your HTML, it is not contained anywhere in your JavaScript, and it is not part of the response you send from the server side either.

Comment: Plus, in both cases you would be inserting `response.message` into the success or error div. But it clearly shows your _full_ server response `{"success": true, "message": "Your message has been sent. Thank you!"}` in there - which would be impossible, if you were really inserting _just_ `response.message`

Comment: I have updated my question to provide better clarity and understanding.

Comment: Can you add `console.log("hello");` after `e.preventDefault();` to show that it's definitely this bit of jQUery code which is handling the form submission? If you submit the form, you should then see that log in the browser's Console. It looks like it should, but would be good to verify - because, still, it seems impossible (as CBroe showed in detail) that the code provided could possibly cause the output you're reporting.

Comment: You could also do things like logging, in the success box, what path the code is taking and what `response` actually contains - either with some console logging, or using the JS debugger in the developer tools